# Limits and multivariable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the limit of the function $f(x,y)$. Note that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-y^2}}{x^2+y^2} 
&\text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\[2pt]
k&\text{if } (x,y) = (0,0). 
\end{cases}
$$

I want to find a function  $F(x) = \lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y)$.

The way I have done has been to first substitute $0$ into $y$, and then I got the first expression, where $x \neq 0$. In the second I used L'Hôpital's rule to get that $k = -1$. Note that on $x \neq 0$ the function is undefined.
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{e^{-x^2}-1}{x^2} 
&\text{if } x \neq 0, \\[2pt] 
-1 &\text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

However, I am in doubt whether my answer is correct.

Comment: What happens when you take the limit along the line $y=x$ instead?

Answer (score 2):

What you've shown so far is that *if* a limit exists, then it is -1. You have not yet shown that a limit exists.

To show that a limit exists, you must show that the value of the limit is the same, independent of the way you approach the point (in this case, the origin).

Your work shows the limit as you approach the origin along the x-axis (when y=0). Try calculating the limit as you approach along a different line (such as the y-axis or the line y=x).